# How do I extract a bunch of images from a page of a book?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm currently trying to build a dataset from bunch of pages of a book. I want to extract the butterflies from the pages into their own images.

Example,

[image: Book page]

I've done a bunch of googling and have only found template matching, but that seems to be only for images of the same type. Plus, since the background is so sparse and there's really nothing else on the pages, I thought I could use that. The resulting images have to overlap, I think, but I also eventually need to remove that overlap and center the images, but I think I can do that.

Is there a way to get the butterflies in the first place?

Comment: If all the text's color is black. I would start with finding contours then check inside of contours if they have different colors crop the contours.

Comment: There are lots of methods to do that (including deep learning), but if all the images are like this one, with thresholding (like Otsu) you can get a good result.

Comment: What language do you want to use here?

Comment: Try Fred Weinhaus's excellent `multicrop` and `multicrop2` scripts http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php They rely on **ImageMagick** being installed. Check licensing if commercial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using thresholding as suggested in the comments, I used Canny edge detection for finding the butterflies, since some of them have spots on their wings close to the edge and with the same color as the book's background, which might cause problems getting the whole wing. Also, since the images are quite large, edge detection seems quite reliable here.

The approach itself is quite simple (I used Python and OpenCV for the implementation):

1. Canny edge detection in image (manually set parameters).
2. Find contours; exclude small contours; draw remaining contours to create a binary mask.
3. Iterate remaining contours; get bounding rectangle; get cropped part of image and mask; "clean" mask by removing potential parts of neighbouring butterflies; create new (cropped) image with transparent background.

Here's the whole code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import platform                     # Only needed for system information
from skimage import io              # Only needed for image web grabbing

# Read image from web; enforce BGR color ordering
image = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwS3g.jpg'),
                     cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Canny edge detection
canny = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 150)
canny = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,
                         cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5)))

# Find contours; use proper return value with respect to OpenCV version
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Filter contours with sufficient areas; create binary mask from them
cnts = [c for c in cnts if cv2.contourArea(c) > 10000]
mask = np.zeros_like(canny)
mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, np.array(cnts), -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Iterate all contours...
for i, c in enumerate(cnts):

    # Get bounding rectangle of contour and min/max coordinates
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    (x1, y1) = rect[:2]
    x2 = x1 + rect[2]
    y2 = y1 + rect[3]

    # Get image section
    crop_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    # Get mask section and cut possible neighbouring contours
    crop_mask = mask[y1:y2, x1:x2].copy()
    cnts = cv2.findContours(crop_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    crop_mask[:, :] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(crop_mask, [c], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

    # Create butterfly image with transparent background
    butterfly = np.zeros((rect[3], rect[2], 4), np.uint8)
    butterfly[:, :, :3] = cv2.bitwise_and(crop_image, crop_image,
                                          mask=crop_mask)
    butterfly[:, :, 3] = crop_mask

    cv2.imwrite(str(i) + '.png', butterfly)

print('------------------')
print('System information')
print('------------------')
print('Python: ', platform.python_version())
print('NumPy:  ', np.__version__)
print('OpenCV: ', cv2.__version__)
print('------------------')
```

Here are two of the saved butterfly images.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

You can slightly blur the alpha channel to get some smoother transition from butterfly to background.

Hope that helps!

```
------------------
System information
------------------
Python:  3.7.1
NumPy:   1.18.1
OpenCV:  4.1.2
------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question - a lot of the resulting images have large areas inside the butterfly that are transparent. How would I remove this so the mask never has a hole in it?

Comment: @Kyranstar You talk about additional images, you're testing on? Because for the given image, the final masks should be fine. (Can't test right now.) In general, that's often the problem, when porting solutions to new images. Try to inspect the intermediate results. Maybe, the Canny parameters need a little adaptation; or the kernel size of the closing needs to be slightly bigger. I doubt, that there'll be parameter set fitting ALL your images. If you find an image, where the presented solution blatantly gives bad results, please add this one to your question and I'll have a look!